# Find entity filtered by a related entity that is in a collection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using Spring Data JPA for my repository layer and spring security as my security layer. In my project, I have the following unidirectional one-to-many relationship between Department and Employee. Below are snippets of the 2 entities.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="department")
    private Set<Employee> members;        

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...

    private String username;

    ...
}
```

The relationship has to be unidirectional due to certain restrictions and one of my use case is to find the department of a logged in user.

My question is, how do I filter out a Department entity based one the current user logged in (i.e. the current user logged in must match 1 Employee object via the username field) using either spring data query methods or jpql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how my requirement can be fulfilled via Spring Data JPA @Query approach without needing to compare with the Employee object but just the username.

```
@Query("select dept from Department dept inner join dept.members member where member.username = ?1")
Department findDeptByQuery(String username)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `JPQL` you can use `MEMBER OF` collection predicate.

```
//Fetch <YOUR EMPLOYEE ENTITY TO MATCH> or 
//Create an new EMPLOYEE object with its primary key prepopulated if you already know it.
Query query = SELECT d FROM Department d WHERE :employee MEMBER OF d.members
query.setParameter("employee", <YOUR EMPLOYEE ENTITY TO MATCH>);
query.list();
```

Comment: Your answer was close. However I was looking for an approach that does not require comparing with an object.