# Spring data, get entity from list with unidirectional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, psql

I have

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private List<Email> emailList = new ArrayList<>();       

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Email{
    ...

    private String emailAddress;

    ...
}
```

I need to get Person by emailAddress. I saw this answer: [dont like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421938/find-entity-filtered-by-a-related-entity-that-is-in-a-collection).
But i wonder - can i do this with only spring data, i mean - without query.

Comment: Do you mean, without decorating your method with `@Query`?

Comment: What is the problem to use a self descriptive JPQL query with a simple method name? Check Cepr0s asnwer, I will prefer the second approach with @Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Person findPersonByEmailList_EmailAddress(String email);
```

And this as well:

```
@Query("select p from Person p join p.emailList l where l.emailAddress = ?1")
Person getPersonByEmail(String email);
```